# Salting the Password with the Password

Tags: passwords, password-protection

I am developing my first web app that requires a login, and it has come to the point when i must decide how to store the passwords.  I have been doing a lot of reading on the proper way to hash the password and adding a salt.  It occurred to me that most of the ways that are recommended would rely on some variation of information that is stored in the database with the password hash, be it some variation of using all or part of the username as a salt or some other random value.

Instead I was thinking of using the user own password as a salt on the password.  Using an algorithm to jumble the password and adding it to itself in some way as the salt.  Of course this to would be compromised if an attacker got access to both the stored hashes and the source code of the algorithm, but any salt would be compromised in such a situation.  My application really probably does not need this level of security, but it was just something that i started to think about when reading.

I just wanted to get some feedback from some more experienced developers.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Why change what works?

Comment: If you use the (jumbled) password as the salt, then a cracker will no longer need to find a string that hashes to the same value in order to obtain the password, they'll just need to un-jumble the password. Salts are generally stored with the password hash in plain text, so obtaining the salt is easy. Then the only thing protecting your password is the extent to which you've jumbled it, which, unless you really know what you are doing, is likely to have a number of exploitable weaknesses...

Comment: @twalberg I think the concept behind this idea is to eliminate the need of storing the password salt at all.

Comment: Use an existing, widely available, free to use commercial hashing / encryption library or technology instead of trying to code your own.  Otherwise you are invariably putting your users' data at risk as you are obviously not an expert in netsec.  It might be a useful practice exercise to build your own password system, but for any real website or product you should use something reliable.

Answer (score 5):

If you derrive the salt from the password itself, you will loose the whole benefit of salting. You can then build a single rainbow-table to get all passwords, and equal passwords will result in equal hash-values.

The main reason to use a salt is, that an attacker cannot build one single rainbow-table, and get all the passwords stored in your database. That's why you should add a random unique salt for each password, then an attacker would have to build a rainbow table for each password separately. Building a rainbow-table for a single password makes no sense, because brute forcing is faster (why not just stop when the password was found).

Don't be afraid to do it right, often the programing environments have support to create safe hashes and will handle salting for your (e.g. [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for PHP). The salt is often combined with the hash for storing, that makes it easy to store it in a single database field.

I wrote a small tutorial about [securely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), maybe you want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Simply duplicating the password may still be vulnerable to dictionary attacks, e.g. the password "hello" becomes "hellohello", and thus might be part of a dictionary.
2. Using a scrambled password as the salt enables the attacker to use a dictionary and then generate a rainbow table for all entries by adding the scambled password on every entry.
3. Why change a proven algorithm which can be understood by any developer? Just do it the default way and your code will be maintainable by anyone else.

*"My application really probably does not need this level of security"* - until that point in time it was hacked. Use a salt, it takes almost no additional effort. Do it now.

*"eliminate the need of storing the password salt at all"*: the salt can be very small (6 bytes). It will hardly affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wanted to get some feedback from some more experienced developers. Any feedback is appreciated.

John Steven of OWASP performed an analysis, including threat modes, for password storage system. It explains the components and their purpose, like the hash, the iteration count, the salt, the HMACs, the HSMs, etc. See the [Secure Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and [Secure Password Storage paper](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g).

Cracking is not the only threat here. More than likely, the guy trying to break into your organization is going to be using one of the top passwords from the millions of passwords gathered from the Adobe breach, the LinkedIn breach, the Last.fm breach, the eHarmony breach, the <favorite here> breach.... For example:

- [25 most-used passwords revealed: Is yours one of them?](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/25-most-used-passwords-revealed-is-yours-one-of-them/12427)
- [The 30 Most Popular Passwords Stolen From LinkedIn](http://mashable.com/2012/06/08/linkedin-stolen-passwords-list/)
- [Top 100 Adobe Passwords with Count](http://stricture-group.com/files/adobe-top100.txt)

Why bother brute forcing when you have a list of thousands of top rated passwords to use?

So your **FIRST** best defense is to use a word list that filters a user's bad password choices. That is, don't allow user's to pick weak or known passwords in the first place.

If someone gets away with your password database, then he or she is going to use those same password lists to try and guess your user's passwords. He or she is probably not even going to bother brute forcing because he or she will have recovered so many passwords using a password list.

As I understand it, these word lists are quite small when implemented as a Bloom Filter. They are only KB in size even though there are millions of passwords. See Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf) for an in depth discussion.